# Why should I eat pizza?

Tags: the-gold-factory

What effect does eating pizza have? I have currently eaten two pizzas, and haven't noticed any change. Is there any effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This factor your Health value (yes, eating many pizza improves your health). The formulae verified is 3 pizza = 1 Health point.

54 pizza improved my health by 18 then: 54 / 18 = 3

Comment: Eating pizza to improve your health is more legit than eating candy to improve your health...

Comment: @Unionhawk After all, pizza *is* a vegetable now.

Comment: 53/15 is not 3.
If you wanted to calculate how much health you had you'd divide the number of pizzas by 3 instead. so, his health actually improved by 17. and if he got one more, it'd be 18.